# Sorting values in large dictionary fetched from mysql in python

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I connected to mysql database and fetched two columns from mysql with python with

```
    query  = ('select test_id, a_id from b.atc_id_TO_cID ')


    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()



    CountinmyDi = {}

    for row in rows:

            if not row[0] in CountinmyDi.keys():
                    CountinmyDi[row[0]] = 1
            else :
                    CountinmyDi[row[0]] += 1
    for key in CountinmyDi.keys():
                    print str(key) + ":" ,CountinmyDi[key]
```

and created a dictionary CountinmyDi to count the unique items inside the dictionary. Now i have for example :

testA : 2
testB : 82 testC:102 test D : 3 test E:1 and so on .. about 220 items

I want to sort the items inside my dictionary for example increasing to decreasing order based upon their values for instance testC : 102, testB : 82 , testD :3 , test A :2 , test E : 1. I would like to get an idea how i could do that . Thank you and if you need further infos, i could gladly provide.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MySQL, so please remove the tag.

Comment: Why don't you just write the proper query so you don't have to do anything in Python?

Comment: okay sure. i did :) fdavidov

Comment: First, the OP states that he wants to sort the _received_ data; second, I wouldn't re-issue the query just to get the data in a different order. Bad practice (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @StefanPochmann i am trying to learn python and make statistical analysis with it.

Comment: This question is actually not a duplicate of the question it has been flagged a duplicate of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask the database to do it for you, SQL query would be:

```
select test_id, count(*) as count from b.atc_id_TO_cID group by test_id order by count
```

and it will return a 2 column table with **test_id, number of tests with this test_id**

If you can't do it this way, I would use a [Python built-in Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

query  = ('select test_id, a_id from b.atc_id_TO_cID ')
cursor.execute(query)

test_counter = Counter(row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall())

for test_id, count in test_counter.most_common():
    print(test_id, ":", count)
```

Comment: Perfect . Thank you so much Guillaume. It works